# How to include jQuery for use with Rally SDK 2.0

Tags: jquery, rally

I have been using jQuery while developing an app with the Rally 2.0 SDK. Everything works fine when I'm using the debug version of the page but when I upload the HTML from the dev version I'm getting a bunch of syntax errors on the jQuery include. What I've done is download the jQuery 1.7.2 min distro and saved it as jquery.js in the working folder. Then I changed my config.json to:

```
{
    "name": "overview_v2",
    "className": "CustomApp",
    "sdk": "2.0p2",
    "javascript": [
        "App.js",
        "jquery.js"
    ],
    "css": [
        "app.css"
    ]
}
```

When I compile with the Rakefile it includes the jQuery into the HTML correctly but I'm getting a few different errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

and

```
unmatched ) in regular expression
```

The first error comes when loading the page in Google Chrome and the second comes when loading in Firefox. Am I including jQuery the correct way or is there a better alternative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading to the latest version of the app sdk rakefile. There were issues with parsing regular expressions in an earlier version of the rakefile.

Comment: This did the trick. For anyone else that experiences this problem, the working rakefile is found here: https://github.com/RallyApps/AppTemplate/blob/8be48bcb7e458386aa130a829df2b8a096ec2c98/Rakefile

The version found in starter-kit.zip was the problem. Updating it might save some people some frustration.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're using jquery?  The SDK is build using Ext 4, which should provide most if not all the functionality contained in jquery...

Comment: I suppose mainly because of my familiarity with jQuery over the SDK. As I become more experienced with the SDK I'm sure I will transition to using it more exclusively. I also had some animation in my app (slideToggle and fadeToggle) which I wasn't sure the SDK supported natively.

Comment: One other gripe with the Rally SDK has been the documentation. For someone who has never been exposed to Rally, let alone creating apps for it, it is going to be very hard to know exactly what types of things that can be expected to be passed to and from certain functions. For instance models, you can get Tasks, User Stories, Portfolio Items, Users, ect. but how would I find this out having never used Rally before?

Comment: I agree it can be tough to get started- especially if you're new to both the App SDK and Rally's Web Services API.  In this case all the available types and their fields are all listed in the interactive WSAPI documentation here:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/

We have some basic examples of how to do common things in the docs:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p3/doc/#!/example

Over time as the app catalog grows there should be more code to get started with as well.

Comment: Just in time for me to have already learned it all the hard way I would assume :p Seriously though, I can't thank you and the other guys at Rally enough for all your help the last couple weeks! Hopefully if others have the same questions in the future the fact that they are posted here will save you guys some support time. Thanks again!